# Delete tag with specific content in php?

Tags: php

This is my function to delete some tags:

```
private function removeTag($el, $tag) {
        $el = preg_replace("#\<".$tag."(.*)/".$tag.">#iUs", "", $el);
        return $el;
    }
```

How can I extend this function to delete or replace tag with empty string if tag contains word: "*ignore*"

Comment: What does a tag that contains the word "ignore" look like?

Comment: @Daniel it is <p>ignore</p> tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to search for `ignored` within the content of the tag.

```
function removeTag($el, $tag) {
    return (preg_match('/^(.*)+>ignored<(.*)+>$/', $el) === false)
        ? preg_replace("#\<$tag(.*)/$tag>#iUs", "", $el) : $el
}
```

If you want to set the ignored phrase as a param, you can do something like this:

```
function removeTag($el, $tag, $ignored = false) {
    if (!$ignored) return $el;
    else return (preg_match("/^(.*)+>$ignored<(.*)+>$/", $el) === false)
        ? preg_replace("#\<$tag(.*)/$tag>#iUs", "", $el) : $el
}
```

Comment: It is possible to make this phrase "ignored" as a param? Because I have also some other phrases...